# eBay API: get watch count for the particular item

Tags: ebay-api

I want to retrieve a number of watchers for the particular item using eBay API. I tried setting `IncludeWatchCount` to `true` in `GetSingleItem` request, but it appears that it works only for the seller of the item. Is it possible to get the number of watchers without being a seller?

Answer (score 0):

I literally just joined in on SO with a new account because I lost my previous email with which I had the old one just to answer your question.

Anyway, If you call `findItemsAdvanced`, under `listingInfo` there is a `watchCount` field. It only works with `findItemsAdvanced` and not with any other.

**[NOTE] The `watchCount` variable is not in the documentation. You should dump the response given by `findItemsAdvanced`, find `listingInfo` and it will be there**

Comment: hey Mario, is this working for you? i don't see the watchcount variable in there

Comment: Hey. It is not in the documentation. Sorry I didn't mention that, I'll update my answer. But if you dump the contents of the findItemsAdvanced response and the listingInfo within, you will see it.

Comment: Hi. The `watchCount` variable is not there. It's not in the documentation, nor is it in the `listingInfo` in the API response from eBay. Did eBay remove it?

Comment: I built this app with the ebay api http://goiwouldlike.com/. Try searching for, lets say, iphone 7 in any country and you will see the watch count number in the product listing so it should still be there.